# Initialize Ruby class with symbol with two points after (menu:)

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have following class:

```
class Takeaway
  def initialize(menu:)
    @menu = menu
  end

  def print_menu
    menu.print
  end

  private

  attr_reader :menu
end
```

This class passes my test in RSpec:

```
require "takeaway"

RSpec.describe Takeaway do

  subject(:takeaway) { described_class.new(menu: menu) }

  let(:menu) { double(:menu, print: printed_menu) }
  let(:printed_menu) { "Chicken: €3.5" }

  it "shows the menu with the dishes and prices" do
    expect(takeaway.print_menu).to eq(printed_menu)
  end

end
```

I don't understand the line: `def initialize(menu:)`

If I get rid of the two points in menu, test does not pass. What is this object? A symbol?

Comment: It's keyword param:
https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments

Comment: FYI the name of that symbol is "colon". Google for "ruby argument colon"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a feature introduced in Ruby 2.0 called "keyword arguments" which if you've used Python or Objective-C are probably a lot more familiar. A standard argument list looks like:

```
def f(x)   # Example: f(1)
def f(x,y) # Example: f(1,2)
```

Now where defaults are involved:

```
def f(x=1, y=2) # Example: f(0) or f(0, 3)
```

Note here you can't call `f(,3)` if you wanted `x` to use its default value.

The Ruby 2.0 *keyword-argument* version fixes this problem:

```
def f(x:)       # Example: f(x: 1)
def f(x:1, y:2) # Example: f(y: 3)
```

The `x:` with no value following means it a named argument with no default and so is *required*. Calling the method without it produces an error.